# rails 5 way for having order and includes in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have this line in rails 3:

```
has_many :balance_lines, :dependent => :destroy, :include => "budget_item", :order => "budget_items.position"
```

How do I convert it to rails 5?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way:

```
has_many :balance_lines, -> { order("budget_items.position").includes("budget_item") }, :dependent => :destroy
```